# How can I execute the failed state with error code "INCOMPATIBLE_WITH_EXISTING_SESSION" in android dynamic delivery?

Tags: android, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-delivery

According to the Android developer [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/dynamic-delivery#handle_request_errors), the definition of the failed state "INCOMPATIBLE_WITH_EXISTING_SESSION" is

> The request contains one or more modules that have already been requested but have not yet been installed.

I'm testing an Android app with a dynamic feature module which will be downloaded/installed after clicking a button. I want to test the scenario when the install request goes to the failed state "INCOMPATIBLE_WITH_EXISTING_SESSION".
For this purpose, I click the button once and while the request is in "Downloading" state, I click the same button once again (or even couple of times more), but the request won't enter the failed state with the error code "INCOMPATIBLE_WITH_EXISTING_SESSION". As far as I understand these actions should simulate the definition above.

Do you have any explanation on why the failed state is not executed or how I can execute a scenario in which the install request enters the INCOMPATIBLE_WITH_EXISTING_SESSION state.

Answer (score 0):

Do not download two dynamic modules in parallel or request same module more than once until installed state is received.

I have implemented a `Queue` so that even if multiple requests are given, it will execute it one by one. Take second request only if current module is `INSTALLED` or `FAILED` or you get callback in `addOnFailureListener`.